# GitHub import "redirect_uri_mismatch"

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm having a "redirect_uri_mismatch" every time I try to import my GitHub project.

With Firefox when I click to the github link it goes straight to https://careers.stackoverflow.com/?error=redirect_uri_mismatch. With Chrome it first asks me to log in to GitHub and then to the same redirect_uri_mismatch home page.

Comment: I’ve got a repro on this, it has to do with https. You can try it again with plain http in the meantime, or we’ll hopefully have a fix soon.

Comment: With plain http it does work. I'll try again https when that fix is out, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be resolved. We now simply force users to HTTPS when interacting with GitHub.